# How to implement a java.util.function.Predicate as Kotlin lambda?

Tags: java, lambda, kotlin

I need to pass a `java.util.function.Predicate` to a Java function. How can I implement it as Lambda in Kotlin?

The Java-Function I need to call:

```
public void foo(Predicate<String> p)
```

Java Lambda implemenation ✔ :

```
foo(text-> true)
```

Kotlin Lambda implemenation ❌:

```
foo{text:String -> true}  
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
Type mismatch.
Required: Predicate<String>
Found:    (String) → Boolean
```

---

Kotlin-Version 1.2.21

Comment: I just tried this, it works fine.

Comment: @karandeepsingh which version do you use?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Since Kotlin 1.4**

```
foo({text -> true  })
```

or

```
foo {text -> true}
```

**Before Kotlin 1.4**

These variants work:

```
foo(Predicate {text -> true  })  
foo(Predicate {true})
foo({true  }as Predicate<String>)
```

Comment: so ugly we need to specify Predicate in Kotlin

Comment: @jpganz18 this has been resolved in Kotlin 1.4

Answer (score 3):

If in case want to declare as a property:

```
private val normal = Predicate<Int> { true }
private val even = Predicate<Int> { it % 2 == 0 }
private val odd = even.negate()

fun main() {
 println("Normal count ${get(normal)}")
 println("Even count ${get(even)}")
 println("Odd count ${get(odd)}")

}

fun get(predicate: Predicate<Int>): Int {
 val filter = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10).filter { predicate.test(it)}  
 println(filter)
 val map = filter.map { it * 2 }
 println(map)
 return map.sum()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It works fine, here is a test that compiles with a Java `List` and the `filter` method that takes a `Predicate` as parameter:

```
val test = Arrays.asList("Hello", "Bye", "World!")
println(test)
println(test.filter { it.startsWith("W") })
```

Is the last sample code (`foo{text:String -> true}`) your code that does not compile?

Between the braces, your are supposed to pass the implementation of the lambda, not the type/interface of it. This part is inferred for you!

Comment: The `filter` function is an extension function in Kotlin and takes actually not a `java.util.function.Predicate` argument, that's why your sample works for your sample but not the one in question.

Comment: Oh! I didn't know that. I'm not currently in front of my computer, but I think I double checked it and IntelliJ confirmed me it was a predicate! Nice to know anyway, thanks for your comment :)

Answer (score 1):

As of Kotlin 1.4, there is support for Single Abstract Method (SAM) conversion for Java interfaces:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions

From the example in the question, the following works now:

```
foo { text -> true }
```